# redirect with maipulated host header in php

Tags: php

there is a target site like `https://target.com/` and i have hosted another site like`http://mysites.com/index.php`.
when users connect to my site i want to redirect them to the target site with manipulated `Host header parameter`(for example if in normal the host header is `target.com` i want the user request the redirected site with `Host:google.com` host header value).
what is the simple way to do it ??? i have already tried header in php and didnt get answer and i dont have enough knowledge to use cUrl to redirect users with new host header.

Comment: Have you tried the answers here ? :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: there isnt any discussion about host header parameter in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect in PHP can be done with `header` function: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php In your case it'll look like this:

```
header("Location: http://target.com/");
```

Comment: i mentioned in the question. that i need a way to change host header parameter(which normaly in my example is target.com and i desire to change it to google.com) that user will request.

Comment: and tnx for destroying my question:)

Comment: You can change `host` header when you do request from PHP (from the server side with cURL), but when you redirect user you can't do this because headers are set by the browser. Such change is considered to be a security issue: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46702/how-can-i-control-the-content-of-the-http-host-header-in-requests-issued-from-my